# "Perverse" for movies and scenes

Tags: word-requests

What word can we use to say a movie or scene is perverse? I am thinking of sadistic and violent scenes as this:

[perverse scene from game of thrones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKa4bq7CRqM)

I found 邪僻, but it seems it may only describe people. I also found 變態, but CC in Pleco says it’s slang in that meaning.

Comment: for some bloodcurdling scenes also see crime documentaries (Chinese editions of Australian and American documentaries),esp. 开膛手杰克 Jack the ripper http://www.iqiyi.com/v_19rrjangig.html

Comment: 變態 is the right word, it is not a slang

Comment: Yup, definitely 变态.

Comment: bkrs: 邪僻 亦作“邪辟”。
1) 乖谬不正。
2) 品行不端的人。
(written language): heterodox; perverse; abnormal,,
other words,  **堕落** ,① <思想、行为>往坏里变：腐化堕落。
② 沦落；流落<多见于早期白话>：堕落风尘。
（堕落影片 depraved film）

**有悖常情**  perverse; abnormal  dictall 
3.
Something contrary to ethics or morality. [点击朗读]
不道德的事有悖常理或道德的事

Comment: @user6065 Does this suggest all three are ok? Possibly 墮落 is to be preferred?

Comment: they have different shades of meaning,邪僻,有悖常情 seem to have low usage frequency, 邪僻 is not in 现代汉语词典（１９９８ed。）, not in 小马词典，has no frequency number in bkrs,according to iciba it is used in medicine: [医]pathogen； pathogenic factors,if you submit e.g. 邪僻场面 to iciba you get 百姓还行邪僻的事.(corrupt practices), and Bible phrase 箴4:24你要除掉邪僻的口, 弃绝乖谬的嘴.froward mouth, (antiquated?),有悖常情 also has no frequency number and is not in 现代汉语词典, 悖 itself has #25623,常情, reason common sense, has #61843, 堕落 has #7777,

Comment: As a matter of fact, I never heard of "邪僻" before ...

Comment: note that bkrs uses the abbreviation wr apparently meaning "written language" for 邪僻, which may be due to the fact that from the relatively frequently used individual characters readers will understand the meaning
of the combination

Answer (score 2):

For something that is hard to watch, you could say 不堪。变态 is okay, but I think it's usually used to describe people, not scenes and things.

For example, i think you could say something like this:

> Joffrey 拷打妓女的场面很不堪！

This is what my Chinese friend told me when I asked her, anyway. In casual conversation, 变态、不堪 should both be okay.

Answer (score 2):

We always use the word "少儿不宜" to describe these kind of thing(sex, violent, etc.), it translates to "not suitable for children".

少儿(children)不宜(not suitable)

Example:
"perverse scene from game of thrones"="权力的游戏/里/少儿不宜的/场景"